# Compiles using clang, but not g++5 - ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: opencv, c++11, g++, pthreads, clang

I have an OpenCV program that compiles using clang without and errors, I am looking to try and compile this program using g++5 however I am getting the following error:

```
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

The command I am using when trying to build the file is:

```
g++-5 -std=c++11 -pthread main.cpp -o testcomp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

Am I correct in assuming that the OpenCV libraries are 32 bit but g++5 is designed for 64 bit?

If I try to compile the code using the following command, the program builds successfully:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -pthread main.cpp -o testComp `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`
```

I am using OSX and have installed g++ through home-brew.

The full compilation error is below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::drawMatches(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&, cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&, std::vector<cv::DMatch, std::allocator<cv::DMatch> > const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      processingThread(cv::Mat, int)  in ccw6qwZp.o
  "cv::FeatureDetector::create(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccw6qwZp.o
  "cv::DescriptorExtractor::create(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccw6qwZp.o
  "cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in ccw6qwZp.o
  "cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccw6qwZp.o
  "cv::FeatureDetector::detect(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat const&) const", referenced from:
      preProcessing()     in ccw6qwZp.o
      processingThread(cv::Mat, int)  in ccw6qwZp.o
  "cv::DescriptorMatcher::match(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::DMatch, std::allocator<cv::DMatch> >&, cv::Mat const&) const", referenced from:
      processingThread(cv::Mat, int)  in ccw6qwZp.o
  "cv::DescriptorExtractor::compute(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat&) const", referenced from:
      preProcessing()     in ccw6qwZp.o
      processingThread(cv::Mat, int)  in ccw6qwZp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Compiler output as per comment with `-Wl,-v` added:

```
collect2 version 5.2.0
/usr/bin/ld -dynamic -arch x86_64 -macosx_version_min 10.11.0 -syslibroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -weak_reference_mismatches non-weak -o testcomp -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc5/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0/5.2.0 -L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc5/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0/5.2.0/../../.. -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib -v /var/folders/nc/_drhkj6n3fnd1g3jmwq8mtm80000gn/T//ccfpdMCy.o -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_ocl -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab -lstdc++ -no_compact_unwind -lSystem -lgcc_ext.10.5 -lgcc -lSystem
@(#)PROGRAM:ld  PROJECT:ld64-253.3.3
configured to support archs: armv6 armv7 armv7s arm64 i386 x86_64 x86_64h armv6m armv7k armv7m armv7em
Library search paths:
    /usr/local/lib
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc5/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin15.0.0/5.2.0
    /usr/local/Cellar/gcc5/5.2.0/lib/gcc/5
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/usr/lib
Framework search paths:
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "cv::drawMatches(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&, cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> > const&, std::vector<cv::DMatch, std::allocator<cv::DMatch> > const&, cv::Mat&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, std::vector<char, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      processingThread(cv::Mat, int)  in ccfpdMCy.o
  "cv::FeatureDetector::create(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccfpdMCy.o
  "cv::DescriptorExtractor::create(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      __static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int) in ccfpdMCy.o
  "cv::imread(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)", referenced from:
      _main in ccfpdMCy.o
  "cv::imshow(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, cv::_InputArray const&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccfpdMCy.o
  "cv::FeatureDetector::detect(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat const&) const", referenced from:
      preProcessing()     in ccfpdMCy.o
      processingThread(cv::Mat, int)  in ccfpdMCy.o
  "cv::DescriptorMatcher::match(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::DMatch, std::allocator<cv::DMatch> >&, cv::Mat const&) const", referenced from:
      processingThread(cv::Mat, int)  in ccfpdMCy.o
  "cv::DescriptorExtractor::compute(cv::Mat const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&, cv::Mat&) const", referenced from:
      preProcessing()     in ccfpdMCy.o
      processingThread(cv::Mat, int)  in ccfpdMCy.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: Does adding `-m32` to the `g++-5` call fix this?

Comment: I tried `g++-5 -m32 -std=c++11 -pthread main.cpp -o testcomp \`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv\` ` it results in more errors with the end line being `ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386`

Comment: maybe try adding `-Wl,-v` to the initial `g++-5` call to the linker output, it could contain more relevant information.

Comment: Added compiler output to original question with those options enabled.

Comment: thanks, this did not give anything valuable that I could use to determine the cause, but then again I don't use OS X on a daily basis. I supposed that ld might not complain if it was unable to locate the library so I asked for the output but I just checked on an OS X machine that it does complain. About your point that OpenCV is 32bit - then I suppose `-m32` should have helped, but I could be wrong. Does adding `-stdlib=libstdc++` make anything better?

Comment: Where about in the command should I add that?

Comment: It is a `gcc` flag so after `-std=c++11` should be fine.

Comment: That's what I thought but it's giving the error: `g++-5: error: unrecognized command line option '-stdlib=libstdc++'`

Comment: If you are still working on this - I found that g++5 introduces new ABI (http://fedoramagazine.org/gcc-5-in-fedora-whats-an-abi-and-what-happens-when-we-change-it/) so it might as well be that the binaries built with clang are simply incompatible. As far as I understand newer clang versions try to introduce compatibility with this ABI, but I couldn't find any article on which version exactly. So either maybe try to upgrade clang or compile OpenCV with g++5.